# Cross compiling wxWidgets for beaglebone, gtk library not found

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile wxWidgets for my beaglebone black from a ubuntu system. Configure works as expected when passed --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf, but make hits errors when it tries to find the gtk libraries.

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-x11-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-x11-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangoft2-1.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreetype
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgthread-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lSM
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-x11-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-x11-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangoft2-1.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreetype
```

Are there any workarounds? can I just create a symbolic link to the normal gtk libraries? (If so,m how would I do that?)

Comment: 1. Do you have these libraries (.so files) in /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib ?
2. No, you can't link against x86 libraries

Comment: Whats the best way to add those libraries to the arm toolchain? Is there a package I can apt-get?

Comment: What OS are you using and are you going to use that OS on the BeagleBoard itself?

Comment: You need to configure your ubuntu for multiarch support and install packages for armhf platform using apt-get.